# Mac freezes after login

Tags: macos, ios, mac, performance

My mac laptop freezes after I login with correct password. All I see is my wallpaper. after that the rainbow thing starts spinning.

I tried to start in safe mode but that didn't help either. I also tried to login with the guest account but the same error happens. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Sadly, this is a very broad issue, and unfortunately it's difficult to solve over the internet with so little information.** I'll give as much help as I can, but you're probably best following online guides until you can come back with more information. [MacWorld](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/steps-take-when-your-mac-wont-start-3423817/) has a good guide, as does [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/217158/what-to-do-when-your-mac-won%E2%80%99t-start-up/) and [a host of others.](https://www.google.com/#q=mac+won%27t+boot) Given what you've done so far, I'll try to help, updating this post as you complete steps. Comment and let me know what the results are.

1. First, let's run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) or [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731). This will help us find out if your issue is hardware or software based. If your mac was made *after* June 2013, use [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731). Otherwise, use [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257). If this fails, you're probably in big trouble (although it probably won't.) Best case, you simply don't have it installed for a variety of reasons. Normally, if your Mac is new enough (again, almost certainly), it'll automatically start using internet based AHT. However, if it didn't connect (or can't) connect to the internet, you might be able to create a bootable version of AHT on an external drive. Follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest) and see if that works.